# How to increase the speed of vtigercrm Opportunity Module

Tags: mysql, vtiger, vtigercrm

I am currently developing vtigercrm 7.1.0 open source. Vtiger uses mysql for its database and the crm is spilt into multiple modules. The opportunity module is the heart of the crm and contains most of the system fields. As i have been working on the system and adding more fields to the Opportunity module it has been getting progressively slower. I now have over 500 fields in the opportunity module. Each time i add a new field it creates a new column in mysql table `vtiger_potentialscf`.
If i run `select * from vtiger_potentialscf` it takes around 10 seconds to finish the query which has a detrimental effect on the end user who has to wait around 13 seconds for the webpage to load. I have read up on mysql and it doesn't like tables with too many columns. 
I have been working on this system for months now but feel if i cant find a way to improve the speed i will have to look for an alternative CRM system. Does anyone have any helpful suggestions to improve the speed?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you should check -

1. Do you really need 500 fields for a module? Can they be moved to other modules or merged in someway to reduce the field count?
2. Run an explain on the query and see why it is taking that long.
3. Add indexes on the cf table - usually the potentialid column should be the index but it is possible that is fragmented. You can try [defragmenting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html) the table
4. Try moving some of the fields to the main vtiger_potential table or even a third vtiger_potentialcf1 table to split the data further.
5. Try altering the mysql configuration for optimal performance. There are multiple guides available over the internet (even stackoverflow has some).

Let me know how it goes for you.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size, # cores of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From SSH root login, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: While i was developing the CRM I ran into an issue adding fields to the opportunity module this only happen after i had around 300 columns in the table. Each time I tried to add a field i was getting an error "field could not be created" on vtigerscrm front end. I then looked at the database and changed some varchar(255) to TEXT datatype in that table.

Comment: This allowed me to continue adding more fields. Every now and then i would have to change more from varchar(255) to text to add another field to the module. (The table was not able to store more than row size 8126) This is my problem. If i script the table and try recreating it i get an error code 1118 maximum row size. I did some research and changed my.cnf file with the following: InnoDB file type to Barracuda, increased log file size and set row format to compressed. None of theses changes have help. I know why its running slow because the table is full. how do i solve this.

Comment: @pinaki tried to defrag but got the error message Row size too large

Comment: @RustyHamster - you are hitting the max allowed columns for mysql which is expected. Innodb allows upto 1017 columns but that depends on the column type which is why you are able to create more columns when you are reconfiguring the column types. BTW, what is the use case for having 500 fields?

Comment: @RustyHamster - try creating the same column in the vtiger_potential table and copy the data. Then you can alter table to drop the column from cf table and update the tablename pointer in the vtiger_field table. If you move around 300 columns from cf to the main table, I would think you should see significant performance increase

Comment: @pinaki I am building a CRM that collects information on mortgage applications more specifically on self build mortgages. We do a factfind on our clients and gather allot of information about their selfbuild, personal finance, existing properties, debts ect ect ect. hence all the fields. I will try your suggestion on altering the table and see if that helps thanks